# Sending Values to a label causes the program to loop and causes a stack overflow error

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, button, label

this has been driving me completely insane! I am trying to calculate values and return those values to a label in my program.  It is quite long and here is just an example.  When I go to compile it, it loops every time a "label18.Text = String.Format(l.ToString("F1"));" or the like is run.  For example, this program would operate in order until it reached label 18, then it goes back to declaring h,w,l again and converting each user input to be a double for calculation.  These loops add up and have eventually caused a stack overflow as my program increased in size.  Help me please! Is there some setting in the label that is causing this?

```
        private void calculateModes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Declare, Convert, and Display variables

        double h,w,l;

        h = Convert.ToDouble(height.Text.ToString()); //(height);
        w = Convert.ToDouble(width.Text.ToString()); //width
        l = Convert.ToDouble(length.Text.ToString()); //length

        label18.Text = String.Format(l.ToString("F1"));
        label19.Text = String.Format(w.ToString("F1"));
        label21.Text = String.Format(h.ToString("F1"));}
```

Comment: Compiling doesn't cause stackoverflow, maybe you meant run it. But when does it happen? On button click? Because that code looks harmless.

Comment: it happens on a button click

Comment: @LewsTherin You are correct, the code does look harmless.  I'm wondering if there are any event listeners that are triggered during the label change?

Comment: and yes, i meant run it.  I used to only use commandline coding so this forms is like a different language and is kind of confusing.  I could not tell what was happening until i walked through the program step by step.  I set the label property of "Text Changed" to "calculateModes_Click" so that the label's text would change when the button was clicked.  Could this cause the loop? the text of the label did not change otherwise

Comment: Where comes length (height/width) variable? Maybe it is the text from label18? And on TextChanged of that label(s) you are calling that calculateModes_Click?

Comment: @SarahK Yes not a loop.. recursion

Comment: the variables are user input from a masked text box

Answer (score 2):

As an option: Try to check `label 18`'s Properties/Events and see isn't there `TextChange` event handler set to `calculateModes_Click`.

Comment: yes, there is an event handler under the TextChange Option that is set to calculateModes_Click

Comment: so, what am I supposed to do instead?

Comment: @SarahK, just remove it. Double click and delete.

Comment: @Dmytro the button or the textchange option?

Comment: @SarahK, textchange option

Comment: oh, i get it. the texchange option launches that program when the text is changed

Comment: @SarahK, .. and it causes the loop, yes.

Comment: @Dmytro which is not a loop, but recursion of the same event. correct?  And the label should be able to change values without any adjustment to its properties using the above code?

Comment: @SarahK, `calculateModes` button changes the values, not label. Label just displays them.